# Can't edit /etc/profile on my mac

Tags: mac, bash

In terminal, I do this:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile
```

But I get a read-only version.  I've never not been able to edit anything as a super user- What's going on?

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/profile` say?  `-r--r--r--`?

Answer (score 10):

`/etc/profile` is readonly.

You can make it writable with

```
$ sudo chmod +w /etc/profile
```

or better yet in `vi`, overwrite a readonly file with `Esc-wq!`

Comment: `Esc-wq!` is a great tip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is not what you are after, but if you can create a `.profile` file in your home directory and put your user-specific configuration changes in there and then you don't need to worry about the one in /etc/profile. However, perhaps you are looking to change the configuration for all users and not just a single user. If so, then the above two answers are on target.

Answer (score 1):

Running `ls -l` on `/etc/profile` reveals that not even the owner has write permission:

```
$ ls -la /etc/profile 
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  189 May  4  2009 /etc/profile
```

You can let the owner edit it like this:

```
sudo chmod u+w /etc/profile
```

Then you should be able to edit it as `root`.