# Cannot edit /etc/profile on my mac

Tags: macos

The answers in the previous question did not help - [Can't edit /etc/profile on my mac](https://superuser.com/questions/251249/cant-edit-etc-profile-on-my-mac)

I want to edit /etc/profile but I can't, even when I open it with sudo.  I manually changed the permissions on the file with

```
sudo chmod u+w /etc/profile
```

And now I get a different error when I try to save the file.  Instead of it telling me I don't have permission, the dialog simply says "The document 'profile' could not be saved."  How can I change the file?

Comment: What program are you using to edit the file via sudo?

Comment: I am using TextEdit

Comment: You should use an editor inside the Terminal, such as emacs, vi, or pico.  Running a window app such as TextEdit as sudo does not work.  (Specifically, you should run "sudo emacs /etc/profile" or "sudo vi /etc/profile")

Comment: `u+w` isn't what you want... you aren't the user... you want to give group/other write if you are going that route. `sudo chmod go+w /etc/profile`.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you run the executable as root:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

If you run `sudo chmod u+w /etc/profile` and open `/etc/profile` normally with TextEdit, TextEdit shows an error because it doesn't have write permission to `/private/etc/`. TextEdit has also required write permission to the containing directory since 10.7, which might have something to do with auto-save or sandboxing.